# Adding a Write Progress bar to a script Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm actually writing a powershell script that sort pictures and videos by dates. The script works fine but i would like to add a progress bar, and i don't know where to start, this might be a bit tricky for me, that's why i'm looking for help.

Here is the function that sort pictures

```
foreach ($file in $Images) 
{
    $Directory = $destinationDirectory + "Pictures\" + $file.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString('yyyy') + "\" + $file.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString('MMM') 

if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
{

    New-Item $directory -type directory
}

Copy-Item $file.fullname $Directory 
}
```

I read the documentation about the Write-progress function but i really don't know how i'm supposed to manage it in this script

Comment: Hi there.  You need to post some code for your progress bar - make an attempt at it before posting here and saying "I don't know how to start".  That's fine conversationally with colleagues but here at SO people expect more up front. 
 Otherwise people will downvote you.

Comment: Hi! 
Yes, of course, I agree. 
I was in a hurry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Write-Progress cmdlet needs a bit of math to make it work for your situation. This should do it:

```
$i = 1
foreach ($file in $Images)
{
    $Directory = $destinationDirectory + "Pictures\" + $file.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString('yyyy') + "\" + $file.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString('MMM') 

    if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
    {
    New-Item $directory -type directory
    }
Copy-Item $file.fullname $Directory
[int]$Percent = $i / $Images.count * 100
Write-Progress -Activity "Copying photos" -Status "$Percent% Complete:" -PercentComplete $Percent
$i++
}
```

First, start with a counter variable `$i` and set it to 1 to represent the first item. This is setup outside the loop so that it doesn't reset back to 1 every time the loop runs.

Then, inside the loop the `$Percent` variable is defined by dividing the value of `$i` by the number of items and multiplying it by 100. Then, `Write-Progress` is called with the necessary parameters to display the progress. Then the counter is incremented upward by one using `$i++`.

Side note: `$Percent` is set to be an integer by placing `[int]` in front of it, which forces it to display whole numbers. If you want to see fractional values, just remove the `[int]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to hold the count of files copied, increment it for each operation, then display the percentage.  The example for [Write-Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-6) has a pretty good example.

I'd recommend using the PowerShell pipeline as well instead of a `foreach`.

Something like this (remove the `-WhatIf`s when you're ready):

```
$images |
    ForEach-Object 
    -Begin { 
        $filesCopied = 0
    } `
    -Process {
        $Directory = "$destinationDirectory\Pictures\$($_.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString('yyyy'))\$($_.LastWriteTime.Date.ToString('MMM'))"

        if (!(Test-Path $Directory)) {
            New-Item $directory -type directory -WhatIf
        }

        Copy-Item $_.fullname $Directory -WhatIf

        $filesCopied += 1
        Write-Progress -Activity "Copied $_.FullName" `
            -CurrentOperation "Copying $_" `
            -Status "Progress:" `
            -PercentComplete (($filesCopied / $Images.Count) * 100)
    }
```

Comment: this not work in ForEach-Object with -Parallel argument